Looking for a counterexample for a conjecture about union-closed families of sets
(I have posted a corrected version of this question. The limit $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ must be replaced with $\lceil (n+1)/2 \rceil$.)
I have already asked basically the same question here, but now I have found a way to rephrase it simply, so this new formulation might be more interesting.
Consider a union-closed family $\mathcal{F}$ of $n$ finite sets with $\mathcal{F} \not = \{ \emptyset \}$.
Let $\mathcal{H} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ be the family of all sets in $\mathcal{F}$ which are (not necessarily proper) supersets of at least $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ of the sets in $\mathcal{F}$.
I conjecture that there always exists a non-empty set in $\mathcal{F}$ which is a subset of at least $| \mathcal{H} | - 1$ of the sets in $\mathcal{H}$.
Can we say something or find a counterexample for this conjecture?
I have tried many examples but couldn't find a counterexample.
Proving the conjecture should be difficult, because I believe it implies the union-closed sets conjecture, however finding a counterexample might be easier and could provide a "difficult" example for the union-closed sets conjecture.
If someone wants to experiment, I have written a python program: given an input family on the standard input (use an empty line for the empty set), it removes duplicates and adds all missing unions of some of its sets, in order to obtain a closed family, then verifies the conjecture:
Here it is run over this example, and here over an example similar to this one where the conjecture is satisfied for $| \mathcal{H} | - 1$ sets in $\mathcal{H}$ and not for all of them.

I downvoted. Your terminology is bad. Do you mean $\mathcal{H} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{F})$ instead? You shouldn't keep saying "sets"; you should say, e.g., "collections" when referring to things like $\mathcal{F}$. Anyways, I have no idea how $\mathcal{H}$ is defined. If $\mathcal{F} = {\emptyset,{1},{2},{1,2}}$, what is $\mathcal{H}$? I would vote to close your question.

@mathworker21 The terminology seems correct and clear to me. A slight ambiguity is due to the verb "to contain" which is commonly used both in the sense of "as a subset" (like here, as I understand) and "as an element". I guess you would prefer "include".

@PietroMajer: I agree with mathworker21. I have no idea how to parse the sentence "Let $\mathcal{H} \subset \mathcal{F}$ be the family of all sets containing at least $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ sets of $\mathcal{F}$ (the set itself is counted)." Can you explain the meaning of this sentence? Can you answer mathworker21's question about if $\mathcal{F}={\varnothing, {1},{2},{1,2}}$, what is $\mathcal{H}$?

I may be wrong, but it seems very clear to me. As I wrote: read "containing" = "containing as a subset". In the above example $n=4$ and  $\mathcal{H}={ {1},{2},{1,2}}$. Consider e.g.  the set $H={1,2}\in\mathcal F$.  It includes as subsets all the $4$ elements of $\mathcal F$, more than $4/2$, so $H\in\mathcal H$. The empty set only includes $1$ element of $\mathcal F$, $1$ is less than $4/2$, so $\emptyset\notin \mathcal H$.

@PietroMajer: ah, okay, that does clarify, thanks! EDIT: I edited the question to hopefully make its meaning crystal clear.

@PietroMajer thank you for the comments.

@PietroMajer Thanks for clarifying. [Now that I understand what "contain" is referring to, I think it's much better than "include" though :P]

See Peter Frankl's open question here: https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/3.2.pdf (see Exercise 6.3:22)

Is it easy to see why this implies the union-closed sets conjecture?

@AlecEdgington the reason is explained in the question linked at the beginning, where it is said that a set can appear in maximum $h-2$ expression there.

A specific corollary of your conjecture is that there is a set in $\mathcal{F}$ that contains/has at most one non-abundant element. This corollary quickly implies the union-closed conjecture.

@mathworker21 could you share the deduction of your corollary? Maybe it is simpler than the construction in my linked question.

Counterexample with $|\mathcal F|=n=20$. First partition the set $[18]=\{1,2,3,\dots,18\}$ into the disjoint sets
$A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $B=\{5,6,7,8\}$, $C=\{9,10,11,12\}$,
$X=\{13,14\}$, $Y=\{15,16\}$, $Z=\{17,18\}$.
Now define
$\mathcal F=\{\varnothing,A_0,A_1,A_2,A_3,B_0,B_1,B_2,B_3,C_0,C_1,C_2,C_3,X_0,X_1,Y_0,Y_1,Z_0,Z_1,T\}$ where:
$A_0=B\cup C\cup Z$, $A_1=A_0\cup\{1\}$,
$A_2=A_1\cup\{2\}$, $A_3=A_2\cup\{3\}$,
$B_0=A\cup C\cup Y$, $B_1=B_0\cup\{5\}$,
$B_2=B_1\cup\{6\}$, $B_3=B_2\cup\{7\}$,
$C_0=A\cup B\cup X$, $C_1=C_0\cup\{9\}$,
$C_2=C_1\cup\{10\}$, $C_3=C_2\cup\{11\}$,
$X_0=A\cup B\cup C\cup Y\cup Z$, $X_1=X_0\cup\{13\}$,
$Y_0=A\cup B\cup C\cup X\cup Z$, $Y_1=Y_0\cup\{15\}$,
$Z_0=A\cup B\cup C\cup X\cup Y$, $Z_1=Z_0\cup\{17\}$,
$T=A\cup B\cup C\cup X\cup Y\cup Z=[18]$.
To see that $\mathcal F$ is union-closed and $|\mathcal F|=20$, observe that:
$\varnothing\subsetneqq A_0\subsetneqq A_1\subsetneqq A_3$,
$\varnothing\subsetneqq B_0\subsetneqq B_1\subsetneqq B_3$,
$\varnothing\subsetneqq C_0\subsetneqq C_1\subsetneqq C_3$,
$A_0\cup B_0=X_0\subsetneqq X_1\subsetneqq T$,
$A_0\cup C_0=Y_0\subsetneqq Y_1\subsetneqq T$,
$B_0\cup C_0=Z_0\subsetneqq Z_1\subsetneqq T$,
$A_0\cup B_0\cup C_0=T$.
Finally, $\mathcal H=\{X_0,X_1,Y_0,Y_1,Z_0,Z_1,T\}$, so $|\mathcal H|=7$, while each of the minimal nonempty elements of $\mathcal F$, namely $A_0$, $B_0$, and $C_0$, is contained in just $5$ elements of $\mathcal H$.

Cool! Any insight into how you found this?

No no, don't mean to imply that I checked it. Just wondering if you used a computer search or something.

Is that unusual? I definitely don't carefully check the details of every MO post I upvote... just try to discern whether real effort has been put into it and whether it is likely to make a positive contribution. Anyways I guess this is getting a bit off topic from the question at hand...

I checked it and it is correct! Thank you very much. I will study this example to see if it is interesting regarding to the linked question. By the way if we remove the empty set the family satisfies the conjecture. So it would be nice to have a counterexample without the empty set.

Also, this family with or without the empty set is not independent, so maybe I will ask in the future another question with that restriction, since it suffices to prove the union-closed sets conjecture for independent families (extension of the separating property). Thank you very much anyway.

I realized now that I made a mistake in the question. The $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ limit is correct for $n$ odd but needs to be $\lceil (n+1)/2 \rceil$ for $n$ even. In other words it needs to be $n-\lceil n/2 \rceil+1$ for $n$ odd or even. Should I correct the question or start another one? This is because the intersection of all $H_i$ has to give the set of all the abundant elements.

I think a separated question should be better - let this one be dedicated to counterexamples :)

OK started another question. Sorry for the error @bof. Rethinking about it, the requirement that the family be independent should not be relevant here.

The following non-counterexample (it had a mistake) can serve to show that the factor $1/2$ can’t be lowered.
Consider  for instance, for $r\in \mathbb N$, the family
$\mathcal F:=\{F\subset[2r]: |F|\ge r\}$, so that $n:=|\mathcal F|=\sum_{i\ge r}{2r\choose i}=2^{2r-1}+\frac12{2r\choose r}$.
Then in $ \mathcal H$ there are all $H\in\mathcal F$ of cardinality $|H|= 2r-1$, because every such $H$ includes $\sum_{i\ge r}{2r-1\choose i}=2^{2r-2}\sim\frac n2 $ sets $F\in\mathcal F$. But  every $F\in\mathcal F$ fails to be a subset of  at least $r$ elements $H$ of $\mathcal H$, namely
$H_i:=[2r]\setminus \{i\}$ for $i\in F$.

Are you sure? I think it should be $\sum_{i\ge r}{2r-1\choose i}=2^{2r-2}$ (see here) or am I missing something?

yes, I wrongly  did $\sum _{i\le r}$  !    deleting

well I  edited to keep it, as at least it shows that  n/2 can’t be improved

@PietroMajer Sorry, what factor $1/2$ are you referring to? Why doesn't your answer disprove the OP's conjecture? They ask to show there's some set in $\mathcal{F}$ which is a subset of all but at most one set in $\mathcal{H}$. In your answer $|\mathcal{H}| = 2r$ and each $F \in \mathcal{F}$ is a subset of at most $r$ sets $H \in \mathcal{H}$.

Yes but here for each set $H\in\mathcal H$ there are approximatively $\frac12 n$ subsets $F\subset H$, $F\in\mathcal F$, yet less than $\frac12 n$, which was required.
